# Javascript split a string into an array dictionary (key -> value) (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, dictionary, pattern-matching

The aim is to parse a string into an array dictionary in javascript.

For example this maybe the string that needs to be parsed

"k=23:3/24:32b=43:532:45/3:3253"

---

**I would like that string to turn into a dictionary like so (Key - Value)**

k - 23:3/24:32

b - 43:532:45/3:3253

---

My initial idea was to search for [a-Z]\*.* and split it into matches using regex.

However, I do not think this would work as this would also bring over **b** which is not what I want. Also, I was not able to get this to work (I'm new to regex).

---

An equals will only ever be between a key and variable (never in the value). The key will also only ever be a single character not a word.

```
var test = "k=23:3/24:32b=43:532:45/3:3253";
var r = /(.*)([a-Z])(//*)(*.)/
```

Above was my idea of going about it but I can not seem to get anything to work.

Comment: If the format of the value is also well defined it can make a cleaner regex. It _looks_ like the value is always `(digits):(digits)/(digits):(digits)` -- is that the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly use `/.=[^=]+(?!=)/g` to match the key value pair without further knowledge of what characters are possible for the key and value:

- Here `.=` matches the key (single character) right before the equal sign;
- `[^=]+(?!=)` matches all non `=` characters after until one character before the next equal sign (restrict the greedy match using a negative look ahead) or the end of string;

```js
var test = "k=23:3/24:32b=43:532:45/3:3253";

var result = {}

test.match(/.=[^=]+(?!=)/g).forEach(
  m => {
    var [k, v] = m.split('=')
    result[k] = v
  }
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Do you mean you have `*` as separator for key value pairs? If that's the case, try `/.\*[^*]+(?!\*)/g`, notice you need to escape `*` as it's a quantifier in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since the identifier is only one character and the `=` is where the identifier ends and the value begins, then just do that using a regex like:

```
var r = /.=.+?(?=(.=)|$)/g;
```

Which means:

```
.          : a character
=          : followed by =
.+?        : followed by a bunch of characters (the ? means non-greedy mode: match as few as possible so that it won't consume from other variables)
(?=(.=)|$) : positive look-ahead, means that the above should be followed either by another .= (a character that is followed by =) or the end of the string
```

Then you can `reduce` the matches to get your desired object, by `split`ing each match to get the key-value pairs:

```
var obj = test.match(r).reduce(function(obj, match) {
    var keyValue = match.split("=");
    obj[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

**Example:**

```js
var test = "k=23:3/24:32b=43:532:45/3:3253";
var r = /.=.+?(?=(.=)|$)/g;

var obj = test.match(r).reduce(function(obj, match) {
    var keyValue = match.split("=");
    obj[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```