# Javascript with Regex to split string at different specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
Name=(Last, First), Age=(31 year, 6 months, 3 day), Height= 6.1 ft, Employment=None, Email Address =/NA/, Mobile=XXXX
```

and I would like to split them into the following to build a dictionary

```
Name: "(Last, First)"
Age: "(31 year, 6 months, 3 day)"
Height: " 6.1 ft"
...
```

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124987/javascript-split-a-string-into-an-array-dictionary-key-value-regex) and tried to tweak it but can get it work with keys with/out "()". Here is the code [or from this link](https://jsbin.com/qeyifuteju/1/edit?js,console,output). Would appreciate your help and feel free to suggest easier or alternative way.

```js
txt="Name=(Last, First), Age=(31 year, 6 months, 3 day), Height= 6.1 ft, Employment=None, Email Address =/NA/, Mobile=XXXX"

//var r = /.+?=.+?(?=(\([^)]+\),)|(.=)|$)/g;
//var r = /.+?=.+?(?=(=(.*),)|$)/g;

var r = /.+?=.+?(?=(\),)|(\d\b,)|$)/g;

var obj = txt.match(r).reduce(function(obj, match) {
    var keyValue = match.split("=");
    obj[keyValue[0].replace(/,\s/g, '')] = keyValue[1];
    return obj;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, using a smart lookahead to split conditionally on only the correct commas:

```js
var txt = "Name=(Last, First), Age=(31 year, 6 months, 3 day), Height= 6.1 ft, Employment=None, Email Address =/NA/, Mobile=XXXX"
var map = {};
var parts = txt.split(/,\s*(?![^(]*\))/);
parts.forEach(function (item, index) {
    map[item.split(/=/)[0]] = item.split(/=/)[1];
});
console.log(map);
```

The regex used for splitting requires an explanation:

```
,\s*         match comma with optional whitespace
(?![^(]*\))  assert that we cannot lookahead and see a closing ) without
             first seeing an opening (
```

The lookahead condition prevents matching commas which happen to be inside `(...)` terms.  Then, once we have the array of terms, we iterate and build the dictionary you want, splitting each term on `=` to find the key and value.

Comment: This is great and easier to follow. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I accepted yours. I got two great answers with great explanations. Yours is easier to understand and gives more flexibility once split at the correct commas, e.g. further split inside parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

To match the properties and values, you can use:

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*(\([^)]+\)|[^,]+)
```

- `(\w+)` - Match and capture the property (one or more word characters)
- `\s*=\s*` - Followed by optional spaces, a `=`, and more optional spaces
- `(\([^)]+\)|[^,]+)` - Match and capture either:

  - `\([^)]+\)` - A `(`, followed by non-`)` characters, followed by `)`, OR
  - `[^,]+` - Non-comma characters

```js
const str = 'Name=(Last, First), Age=(31 year, 6 months, 3 day), Height= 6.1 ft, Employment=None, Email Address =/NA/, Mobile=XXXX';

const obj = {};
for (const [, prop, val] of str.matchAll(/(\w+)\s*=\s*(\([^)]+\)|[^,]+)/g)) {
  obj[prop] = val;
}
console.log(obj);
```

If the input keys may contain spaces as well, match anything but a `=`:

```js
const str = 'Employee Name=(Last, First), Person Age=(31 year, 6 months, 3 day), Height= 6.1 ft, Employment=None, Email Address =/NA/, Mobile=XXXX';

const obj = {};
for (const [, prop, val] of str.matchAll(/(\w[^=]+)\s*=\s*(\([^)]+\)|[^,]+)/g)) {
  obj[prop] = val;
}
console.log(obj);
```

If you can't use `matchAll`, then iterate over the matches manually with `exec`:

```js
const str = 'Name=(Last, First), Age=(31 year, 6 months, 3 day), Height= 6.1 ft, Employment=None, Email Address =/NA/, Mobile=XXXX';

const obj = {};
const pattern = /(\w+)\s*=\s*(\([^)]+\)|[^,]+)/g;
let match;
while (match = pattern.exec(str)) {
  const [, prop, val] = match;
  obj[prop] = val;
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for taking the time to explain the regex syntax. One small note is if the key is multi words like "Employee Name", it will only pick "Name". I changed it to ```/\w+\s*\w+\s*=\s*(\([^)]+\)|[^,]+)``` and it worked (same with ```(\w+\s*\w+)```). It was easier after you explained it. However, I'm not sure what the parenthesis in ```(\w+)\``` is for?

Comment: If the "key" can contain spaces, I guess you could match anything but an `=` instead of `\w+`. The parentheses *capture* the part parentheses - they're called capturing groups, they allow you to extract the sub-matches there outside in Javascript - the matched key portion in the parentheses goes into the `prop` variable because it's the first capture group.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to match but an ```=``` instead of ```\w+```. It seems the change I made is unnecessary but not sure how capture everything before ```=```.

Comment: To match anything but a `=`, use a negative character set, `[^=]`, see snippet